# Posting image as Base64 string using loopJ Asynchronous Http Client

Tags: android, base64, loopj

Hello i am using loopJ [Asynchronous Http Client](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) for posting values to a webservice. The problem i am facing is. I encode my Bitmap to Base64 String and use this string as a parameter for the webservice. I always get the ClientProtocolException and no response. I know there is a problem with the string. But i dont know what the problem is maybe a large string ? I need help.

Here is my code

```
client.get(
                "http://website.com/users.php?task=addGeneralSettings&userID="
                        + user.getUserID() + "&vat="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(user.getVat()))
                        + "&company=" + URLEncoder.encode(user.getCompany())
                        + "&address1=" + URLEncoder.encode(user.getAddress1())
                        + "&address2=" + URLEncoder.encode(user.getAddress2())
                        + "&telephone=" + user.getTelephone() + "&fax="
                        + user.getFax() + "&email=" + user.getEmail()
                        + "&website=" + URLEncoder.encode(user.getWebsite())
                        + "&vatNum=" + URLEncoder.encode(user.getVatno())
                        + "&CompanyReg="
                        + URLEncoder.encode(user.getCompanyNum()) + "&logo="
                        + (user.getLogo()), new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                    public void onSuccess(String response) {

                        Log.v("web response ", response);

                        try {
                            json = new JSONObject(response);

                            if (json.getBoolean("status")) {

                                delegate.settingsAdded(user.getLogo());

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                });
```

The getLogo() is my base64 String. Which is huge in length. I am using the following code to convert the Image to Base64 string.

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);


        return imageEncoded;
    }
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and it turned out it wasn't really related to the loopj library. It was that I was encoding my image using a Java byte[] which is signed, and sending it to a web service developed in C# which was using unsigned bytes. Long shot, but maybe this helps.